# Run groovy script from MainActivity/Activity

Tags: java, android, groovy, geb

I'm currently trying to run a groovy script in my MainActivity.

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.grooid.groovy-android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.8'

    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.muco.staemme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}


dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

    compile "org.gebish:geb-core:0.13.1"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0"
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.52.0"

}

android.packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}
```

## Gebbi.groovy (experimental, first i want to make sure, that it runs)

```
package com.example.muco.staemme

import android.util.Log
import geb.Browser


class Gebbi extends Script{

    public String run() {
        Browser.drive {
            go "https://www.die-staemme.de/"
            $("#login_form").with {
                user = "..."
                password = "..."
                cookie = false
            }

            $("span", class: "button_middle").click()
            Log.i("groovy",$("span", class: "button_middle"))
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run this code in my MainActivity(Java), but i always get Errors like

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.groovy.control.io.NullWriter
```

with

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
```

or

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
```

etc.

So can someone pls tell me, how to call the groovy script from JavaActivity? I also tried to call groovy script from java on desktop, it runs there. I searched all topics in Stackoverflow and here the from [doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_integrating_groovy_in_a_java_application).

Greetings

Comment: Why do you try to run Geb inside of an Android application? This seems like a very unusual use case.

Comment: i already tried selendroid, selenium, htmlunit and none of these worked on android. So geb was my last hope for my aim.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you should be using these tools from a test to drive the emulator/device running your application under test and not from within an android application thus you shouldn't try to load Geb scripts from within an activity. Also, you shouldn't try to use regular drivers like html unit because they won't work, you will need an android specific driver like selendroid. I would suggest going back to using plain selendroid first, getting that working (I'm pretty sure it will) and then trying using selendroid as the driver together with Geb if you still wish to use Geb.

Comment: I could not manage to let selendroid work. After i add the dependencies for selendroid, i cant run my app anymore because there are always tons of errors because of the lib. I already asked on stackoverflow, but noone could help.